# JavaFx stop scene

Tags: javafx

I'm new in JavaFx and still going through tutorials. I have this small game to create and I divided my display in classes. There is the menu class, game class etc.. I placed my start and main method in the menu class. What I'm doing is creating an instance of the menu class and set the scene to this class'scene. I need a way to stop the scene once a button has been pressed from this class.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Buccanner");
        primaryStage.setWidth(640);
        primaryStage.setHeight(480);

        //Start with Menu
        BuccannerMenu menu = new BuccannerMenu();
        Scene scene = new Scene(menu.createContent());

// So right here, the scene should stop in the menu class and the following commands should be executed. Any idea plz?

//Start Game Scene
        Scene theScene = new Scene(createContent());
        primaryStage.setScene(theScene);

        primaryStage.show();

    }
```

Ps: I can't use Fxml

Comment: What does "stop the scene" mean?

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant like it stops displaying or exit and would then go the other scene